# A conjectured criterion for a generalized ramanujan tau function

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, modular-forms, conjectures, mobius-function

Given [Ramanujan tau function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function) $\tau(n)$, which is the nth Fourier coefficient of the modular discriminant

$\displaystyle \Delta(q)=q\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-q^m)^{24} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n)\,q^n\tag{1a}$

Nothing forbids us from generalizing the generating function to

$\displaystyle \Delta_{k}(q)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau((2k-1)n)\,q^n\tag{1b}$

for integers $k\gt0$

After some experimentation with wolfram mathematica, one discovers the following intriguing patterns

$\Delta_{1}(q)=q^{\color{blue}{1}}-24q^2+252q^3-1472q^4+4830q^5-6048q^6-16744q^7+84480q^8-113643q^{\color{blue}{9}}-115920q^{10}+543612q^{11}-\cdots$

$\Delta_2(q)=252q-6048q^2-113643q^{\color{brown}{3}}-370944q^4+1217160q^5+2727432q^6-4219488q^7+21288960q^8-73279080q^9-29211840q^{10}+134722224q^{11}+167282496q^{12}-145589976q^{13}+101267712q^{14}-548895690q^{15}+248758272q^{16}-1740295368q^{17}+1758697920q^{18}+2686677840q^{19}-1791659520q^{20}+1902838392q^{21}-3233333376q^{22}+4698104544q^{23}-9600560640q^{24}-6425804700q^{25}+3494159424q^26+1665188361q^{\color{brown}{27}}+\cdots$

$\vdots$

From which we deduce the following conjecture

> The nth coefficient $\tau((2k-1)n)$ is odd **if and only if** the powers of q in the partial sum of $(1b)$ depend on whether $(2k-1)$ is square-free or non square-free as follows

$n\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \begin{cases}{\color{brown}{(2k-1),9(2k-1),25(2k-1),49(2k-1),...}} & \mbox{ where $2k-1=1,3,5,7,11,13,...$ is any odd square-free integer}\\{\color{blue}{1,9,25,49,81,...}} & \mbox{ where $2k-1=9,25,27,49,81,...$
is any odd non square-free integer}  
\end{cases}$

**Question**: How do we prove the conjectured criterion?

**Motivation**: The [Möbius function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) $\mu(n)$ is either $1$ or $-1$ if $n$ is [square-free](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) depending on whether it has a number of even prime factors or odd respectively and $\mu(n)=0$ if it is non [square-free](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer). It happens to be a very important arithmetic function in number theory. For example, the Dirichlet series that generates the Möbius function is the reciprocal of the Riemann zeta function $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$

Comment: I just came across the related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71251/converting-an-infinite-product-to-sum-ramanujan-tau-function?rq=1) for the special case $k=1$

Comment: $\tau(n)$ is odd if $n$ is an odd square. So $\tau(kn)$ is obviously only odd if $nk$ is an odd square. (Surely you mean to write $\tau(kn)$ rather than $\tau((2k-1)n)$ is otherwise when $k = 2$ the expression is odd when $n = 3$ which is not part of your conjecture). Anyway, $nk$ is an odd square when $k$ is odd and $n$ is $k$ times an odd square. The converse is true when $k$ is squarefree. But if $k$ is not squarefree they are not equivalent. For example,  $\tau(9n)$ is odd when $n = 1$.

Comment: @user760870: I'm sure everything is clarified now

Comment: And there's one more [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195507/parity-of-ramanujans-tau-function) which mentions that the problem for proving that $\tau(n)$ is odd if and only if $n=(2m+1)^2$ for some $m$ is from Ram Murty's "Problems in the theory of modular forms, exercise 1.5.1"

Comment: What are you rambling about? The case of $k=1$ is given in the link. The case of $k=5$ is false, since $\tau((2k-1)n) = \tau((2 \times 5 - 1) \times 1) = \tau(9 \times 1) = \tau(9)$ is odd for $n = 1$. The correct statement is also obvious from the case $k=1$; $\tau((2k-1)n)$ is odd iff $(2k-1)n$ is an odd square.

Comment: @user760870: btw I'm not rambling okay. I've just modified the post by removing the condition "iff" and clearing things up. The conjecture is not invalidated at all.

Comment: Which of the following completely obvious statements do you not understand?

1. If $n = (2k-1)$ times an odd square, then $(2k-1)n$ is an odd square.

2. If $n$ is an odd square, the link shows that $\tau(n)$ is odd.

3. 1 & 2 together imply that if $n = (2k-1)$ is an odd square, then $\tau((2k-1)n)$ is odd.

Comment: Also your "new" conjecture is obviously false if $(2k-1)$ is any odd multiple of an odd square bigger than $1$, for example if $(2k-1)=27 = 3 \times 3^2$ and $n = 3$ then $(2k-1)n=81$ is a square and $\tau(81)$ is odd. This question has nothing to do with modular forms (beyond the case $k=1$) and is just very elementary arithmetic.

Comment: I have expanded the post and made everything as clear as possible. Of course experimentally the conjecture holds.

Answer (score 3):

What do you get from the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71251/converting-an-infinite-product-to-sum-ramanujan-tau-function?rq=1) (assuming the formula is correct, I didn't find a reference) $$\Delta(q)=q \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(2k+1)q^{k(k+1)/2}\right)^8\equiv q \sum_{k=0}^\infty ((-1)^k(2k+1)q^{ k(k+1)/2})^8\bmod 2$$