# A certain conjectured criterion for restricted partitions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, modular-forms, integer-partitions, q-series

Given the number of [partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ into distinct parts $q(n)$, with the following generating function

$\displaystyle\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1+x^m) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q(n)\,x^n\tag{1a}$

Which may be conveniently generalized into

$\displaystyle q_{k}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty q((2k-1)n)\,x^n\tag{1b}$

for positive integers $k$

After some brute-force experimentation with wolfram mathematica, I discovered the following conjecture analogous to the one discussed in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714660/a-conjectured-criterion-for-a-generalized-ramanujan-tau-function)

The nth coefficient $q((2k-1)n)$ is odd **if and only if**

> the power of the last term included in the partial sum of the generating function $(1b)$ is $n\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\frac{c}{2}$ where $c$ is the solution to this diophantine equation $d^2-12(2k-1)c=1$ which has two unknowns $d$ and $c$
> for every positive integer $k\gt0$

Integer solutions to the diophantine equation above:

Given $e \in \mathbb{Z}$

> $k=1: c=3e^2+e,
>       c=3e^2+5e+2$

> $k=2: c=9e^2+e,
>       c=9e^2+17e+8$

> $k=3: c=15e^2+e,
>       c=15e^2+11e+2,
>       c=15e^2+19e+6,
>       c=15e^2+29e+14$

> $k=4:\dots$

> $\vdots$

For example let $k=3$, then we have the following generating function $q_3(x)=x^{\color{red}{0}}+3x^{\color{red}{1}}+10x^2+27x^{\color{red}{3}}+64x^4+142x^5+296x^6+585x^{\color{red}{7}}+1113x^{\color{red}{8}}+2048x^9+3658x^{10}+6378x^{11}+\dots$

And as per our conjecture we have the corresponding diophantine equation

$d^2-(12×5)c=1$

Then the coefficient $q(5n)$ from the generating function (1b) is odd **iff** the powers of x are

$\frac{15e^2+e}{2}: \color{red}{8}, \color{red}{31}, \color{red}{69}, \color{red}{122}, \color{red}{190},\dots$

$\frac{15e^2-e}{2}: \color{red}{7}, \color{red}{29}, \color{red}{66}, \color{red}{118}, \color{red}{185},\dots$

$\frac{15e^2+11e+2}{2}: \color{red}{14}, \color{red}{42}, \color{red}{85}, \color{red}{143}, \color{red}{216},\dots$

$\frac{15e^2-11e+2}{2}: \color{red}{3}, \color{red}{20}, \color{red}{52}, \color{red}{99}, \color{red}{161},\dots$

$\frac{15e^2+19e+6}{2}: \color{red}{20}, \color{red}{52}, \color{red}{99}, \color{red}{161},\dots$

$\frac{15e^2-19e+6}{2}: \color{red}{1}, \color{red}{14}, \color{red}{42}, \color{red}{85}, \color{red}{143},\dots$

$\frac{15e^2+29e+14}{2}: \color{red}{29}, \color{red}{66}, \color{red}{118}, \color{red}{185},\dots$

$\frac{15e^2-29e+14}{2}: \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{8}, \color{red}{31}, \color{red}{69}, \color{red}{122},\dots$

for integers $e\in \mathbb{N_0}$

Thus in general it is clear that the powers at which the coefficient $q((2k-1)n)$ is odd occur when $n\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\frac{c}{2}$ where $c$ is the solution of the general diophantine equation $d^2-12(2k-1)c=1$

**Question**: How do we prove the conjecture?

Comment: What does "the degree of the generating function (1b) " mean?

Comment: @Somos: I meant the nth degree of the partial sum of the infinite series (1b)

Comment: In (1b), the left side depends on $n$ but not on $x$, while the right side depends on $x$ but not on $n$. That can't be right.

Comment: I don't understand "where $c$ is the solution to this diophantine equation $x^2-12(2k-1)c=1$". which has two unknowns $x$ and $c$ given $k$. If $c$ is the solution, then what is $x$? Okay, I see now. for $k=1$ and $c=3e^2+5e+2$ then $$1+12(2k-1)c=(1+6e)^2 = x^2.$$ It could be explained more clearly.

Comment: @Somos: That's right, I'll try to expand the post and explain more clearly

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I've fixed the error

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the question. Let's let $k=1$. Then the conjecture is that $q(n)$ is odd if and only if the degree of the partial sum of $\sum_0^{\infty}q(n)x^n$ is $n=c/2$ where $c$ is $3e^2+e$ or $3e^2+5e+2$ where $e$ is an arbitrary integer. But what is meant by "the degree of the partial sum of" that power series?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: the degree refers to the power of the last term included in the partial sum

Comment: So, the whole phrase, "the power of the last term included in the partial sum of the generating function (1b) is" could be deleted, with no change of meaning, and a great gain in clarity, isn't that right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes it can

Answer (score 1):

The [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) states

> $$ \prod_{m=1}^\infty 1-x^m = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k x^{k(3k-1)/2}
> = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \Big(x^{k(3k+1)/2} + x^{k(3k-1)/2}\Big). $$
> In other words,
> $$ (1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\cdots = 1 - x - x^2 + x^5 + x^7 - x^{12} - x^{15}
> + x^{22} + x^{26} - \cdots. $$
> The exponents $1, 2, 5, 7, 12, \dots$ on the right side are given by the
> formula $g_k = k(3k-1)/2$ for $k=1,-1,2,-2,3,\dots$ and are called
> (generalized) pentagonal numbers
> (sequence [A001318](https://oeis.org/A001381) in the OEIS).

Note that

$$ ((6m-1)^2-1)/24 = m(3m-1)/2 = g_m. \tag1 $$

Equivalently, the Diophantine equation

$$ d^2 - 24n = 1 \tag2 $$

has only solutions $\,d = 6m-1\,$ with $\,n = g_m\,$ for some integer $m$. In other words,

$$ n = g_m \quad\text{iff}\quad m = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+24n}}6.
 \tag3 $$

Define the infinite product power series

$$ \prod_{j=1}^\infty (1 - x^j) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n. \tag4 $$

The pentagonal number theorem is equivalent to the statement that
$\, a(n) = 0\,$ iff $\,n \ne g_m\,$ otherwise, $\,a(n) = (-1)^m.\,$
This implies that $\,a(n) \equiv 1 \pmod 2\,$ iff $\, n = g_m\,$ for
some $m$.

Define a related infinite product power series

$$ \prod_{j=1}^\infty (1 + x^j) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q(n)x^n. \tag5 $$

Note that $\,a(n) \equiv q(n) \pmod 2 \,$ because $\, 1 \equiv -1 \pmod 2.$ This implies that $\,q(n)\,$ is odd iff $\,a(n)\,$ is odd and, as previously noted in equation $(2)$, iff $\,n = g_m\,$ for some $m$.

Thus, the conjecture regarding the parity of $\,q(n)\,$ is true.

For example, if $\,n = 15\,$ in equation $(2),\,$ then $\,d=19.\,$ Now
$\,a(n) = -1\,$ is odd and also $\, q(n) = 27.\,$ Now
$\,q(n) = q(1\cdot 15) = q(3 \cdot 5) = q(5\cdot 3) = q(15\cdot 1)\,$
which applies to the conjecture

> The nth coefficient $q((2k-1)n)$ is odd **if and only if** ...

Comment: Since I don't understand the question, I don't see how this answers it.

Comment: I think this should be addressed as a comment since it does not prove how $n\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\frac{c}{2}$ is related to that particular diophantine equation

Comment: @Nicco Thanks for that comment! I have revised my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Nicco Okay. I decided to replace $k$ with $m$ and infinite product index $k$ with $j$.

Comment: @Somos: Using the suggested notation, it becomes clear that your answer only takes into account the nth coefficient $q(n)$ where k=1 instead of the general $q((2k-1)n$ as posed in the question

Comment: @Nicco Better now?

Comment: @Somos: Yes it's much better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147292/discussion-between-somos-and-nicco).